# Padding Css issue-browser compatibility issue

Tags: css

I am trying to give difference padding for browser compatibility issue

```
-webkit-padding-start: 4px 0px; //for google chrome
-moz-padding-start: 3px 0px;    //for Mozilla Firefox
padding: 3px 0;                 // others browser
```

But result is padding:3px 0; take both browser. I need to differentiate it.

Comment: It sounds like an odd request to want browser rendering to be different. Is this to make up for something else that's wrong on the page? If so, it would be better to address that.

Comment: Thank you Mr Lister & Mr Guffa. I made two mistakes. Combine of both answers,css working properly in both browsers. Once again thank you to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should try to use the same style for all browsers. Even if that is a bit more work initially, it makes it easier to maintain. That said,

The `padding-start` styles take a single value, not two values.

Example, syntax for `-moz-padding-start`:

```
-moz-padding-start: <length> | <percentage> | inherit | auto;
```

Example:

```
-moz-padding-start: 10px;
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-padding-start

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in that order, the browsers will use the last declaration: the `padding` will override the `-webkit-padding-start`.
So switch the declarations around.

```
padding: 3px 0;                 // other browsers
-webkit-padding-start: 4px;     // for Google Chrome
-moz-padding-start: 3px;        // for Mozilla Firefox
```

Then `-webkit-padding-start` will override the start value of `padding`.