# JavaScript: Different Padding For Different Browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button, input

How can i use a different padding in Firefox for an Input button. The way it works in Firefox differs from all of the other browser that are accessible on a Windows 10 computer (Not Safari). I tried: `mozPaddingStart` but that didn't work. Here is my code:

```
//TourInputYes Properties
TourInputYes.setAttribute("type", "button");
TourInputYes.value = "Yes";
TourInputYes.style.backgroundColor = "White";
TourInputYes.style.outlineWidth = 0;
TourInputYes.style.fontSize = "25px";
TourInputYes.style.borderStyle = "Solid";
TourInputYes.style.color = "Black";
TourInputYes.style.borderColor = "Black";
TourInputYes.style.marginRight = "50px";
TourInputYes.style.height = "53px";
TourInputYes.style.width = "75px";
TourInputYes.style.mozPaddingStart = "8px 15px";
TourInputYes.style.padding = "10px 15px";

//TourInputNo Properties
TourInputNo.setAttribute("type", "button");
TourInputNo.value = "No";
TourInputNo.style.backgroundColor = "White";
TourInputNo.style.outlineWidth = 0;
TourInputNo.style.fontSize = "25px";
TourInputNo.style.borderStyle = "Solid";
TourInputNo.style.color = "Black";
TourInputNo.style.borderColor = "Black";
TourInputNo.style.marginLeft = "50px";
TourInputNo.style.height = "53px";
TourInputNo.style.width = "75px";
TourInputNo.style.mozPaddingStart = "8px 15px";
TourInputNo.style.padding = "10px 15px";
```

If you are wondering, this is part of the code that I am currently working on. The whole code works but, this particular part alone, won't.

**I am looking for a JavaScript solution**

Comment: ... You know, we have a thing called a "stylesheet" using "CSS" that could help here... ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  I know. I was thinking of putting it in HTML and using "Display None" but everything is created in JavaScript. Should I go to HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding Css issue-browser compatibility issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399603/padding-css-issue-browser-compatibility-issue)

Comment: Unless it is your purpose to dive deep into css and browser compatibility, you might want to use some 3rd party library of standard components.

Comment: @VladimirM Not really. I'm asking for a JavaScript solution and not a CSS solution.

Comment: @VladimirM How did you get the impression that I wanted a CSS answer? I don't even have CSS in the tags or Title.